# Calcular derivada e integrais em R

Tags: r

Eu tenho um conjunto de funções que preciso calcular as suas respetivas derivadas e integrais. Por serem muitas achei melhor criar uma função que pega uma expressão como argumento e faz o cálculo da derivada e da integral. O problema é que eu costumo usar `expression` para calcular a derivadas e `function` para calcular integrais (de outra maneira não sei fazer), por exemplo:

Derivada:

```
> y = expression(1/(x+1) * sqrt(x))
> (D.x = D(y, "x"))
1/(x + 1) * (0.5 * x^-0.5) - 1/(x + 1)^2 * sqrt(x)
```

Integral:

```
> y = function(x){1/((x+1) * sqrt(x))}
> integrate(y, lower = 0, upper = Inf)
3.141593 with absolute error < 2.7e-05
```

Eu não quero ter que passar a funcão no parametro duas vezes (uma do tipo `function` para a integral e outra do tipo `expression` para derivada), seria muito trabalhoso. Mas também não sei nenhuma forma de converter um tipo para o outro.

Só para ilustrar, é isso que quero fazer:

```
calcula = function(f, k, a, b)
{
    (D.x = D(f, "x"))
    x = 1
    eval(D.x)
    integrate(f, lower = a, upper = b) #erro aqui
}

calcula(expression(1/(x+1) * sqrt(x), 1, 0, Inf)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja se é isto que quer.
O truque é usar `body` para dar um valor ao corpo da função, tal como está na página de ajuda `help('body')`.

```
calcula <- function(e, k, a, b){
  D.x <- D(e, "x")
  f <- function(x){}
  body(f) <- as.call(c(as.name("{"), e))
  x <- k
  list(
    derivada = eval(D.x),
    integral = integrate(f, lower = a, upper = b) #erro aqui
  )
}

calcula(expression(1/((x+1) * sqrt(x))), 1, 0, Inf)
#$derivada
#[1] -0.5
#
#$integral
#3.141593 with absolute error < 2.7e-05
```